# Cannot convert string '\xAC\xED\x00\x05~r...' from binary to utf8mb3

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting an exception whenever I run this piece of code :

```
StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SELECT this_.id as id, this_.number_of_hours as number_of_hours, this_.date_start as date_start, this_.date_end as date_end, this_.date_created as date_created, this_.obsolete as obsolete FROM (");
sqlQuery.append(" select tt.* from employee_tracking tt ")
        .append(" inner join contract c on tt.contract_id=c.id ")
        .append(" where tt.obsolete = :OBSOLETE ");
    
// UNION
sqlQuery.append(" UNION ");

sqlQuery.append(" select tt_.* from employee_tracking tt_ ")
        .append(" inner join contract_extension ce_ on tt_.contract_extension_id=ce_.id ")
        .append(" where tt_.obsolete = :OBSOLETE ");
    
sqlQuery.append(") AS this_ ORDER BY id ASC ");


SQLQuery query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
query.setParameter("OBSOLETE", 0);
    
query.addEntity(EmployeeTracking.class);

List lst = query.list();
```

The exception stack trace :

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 3854, SQLState: HY000
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot convert string '\xAC\xED\x00\x05~r...' from binary to utf8mb3
```

This is my server character set config :

```
mysql> use lambda;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb3            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3            |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_danish_ci     |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T, information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
    -> WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation AND T.table_schema = "lambda" AND T.table_name = "employee_tracking";
+--------------------+
| CHARACTER_SET_NAME |
+--------------------+
| utf8mb4            |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)
```

My jdbcUrl :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lambda?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=round
```

I am using the following MySQL Server version :

```
~ % /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --version   
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for macos11 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Any help please will be more than appreciated.

Comment: is there any update related to this question, I facing the same problem but with different constraint

Answer (score 1):

It seems your "OBSOLETE" is passed as Serealized instead of as String cause it's an Object, which saved as String in the Database. Try to use simple "toString()" by passing this parameter.